# Why BadCredentialsException can not be thrown or handled in my customized AuthenticationProvider?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I try to use JWT to secure my resource based on Spring Security to achieve the following:
1. Token invalid or expired, return 401.
2. Successfully authorized but have no right to reach some controllers. Then return 403.
Now there is something wrong with it. I throw BadCredentialsException in my customized AuthenticationProvider (named TokenAuthenticationProvider) while user fails to be authenticated. But it finally returns 403. What can I do to handle the exception and return 403 http code.

I tried to implement AuthenticationEntryPoint but it doesn't work.
And one another way to handle the exception is using customized filter to catch the Exception. But this way definitely doesn't work because even the http response doesn't show 500 BadCredentialsException. So there must be a place already catching this Exception and I can't understand.

TokenAuthenticationProvider.class

```java
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    UserService userService;

    public TokenAuthenticationProvider(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        System.out.println(aClass);
        TokenAuthenticationProvider.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
        return true;
    }
}
```

WebSecurity.class

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .addFilterAfter(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("API");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth.authenticationProvider(new TokenAuthenticationProvider(userService));
    }
}
```

TokenAuthenticationFilter.class

```java
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new TokenAuthentication("hello"));
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

The above code has been simplified. Instead of following a normal process, I directly throw the BadCredentialsException. What can I do to handle this Exception and return 401 http code.

Comment: You add a controlleradvice and map this exception like any other exception?

Comment: No, I do not. There are only these files: TokenAuthentication
TokenAuthenticationFilter
TokenAuthenticationProvider
WebSecurity UserController

Comment: Here is complete code https://github.com/exqlnet/spring-security-demo

Comment: Welll i meant you should ADD a controlleradvice and handle the exception like any other exception in a spring boot application

Comment: I tried. But It's still not working.

Comment: show us the code!

Comment: `But it finally returns 403. What can I do to handle the exception and return 403 http code.` you are saying it returns 403,  but then you are asking how to return a 403? Please clarify your question.

Comment: a thrown `BadCredentialsException` maps automatically to a 401 in standard spring security in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that is last in the spring security chain. And i still don't understand your question, and your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually 401 is expected while throwing BadCredentialsException.

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. It seems that the request has passed the authentication chain and reach the authorization chain so it always return 403. My problem is that why it passes the authentication chain and what can I do to return 401 while BadCredentialsException is thrown.

Comment: You then have to handle the exception yourself, try catch. Wy dont you just use the the built in jwt filter?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know the built in JWT filter before. I'm going to try. But I have no idea  to catch the exception yet. Because it seems caught by a built in exception filter and I can't understand how it works, which leads to no exception thrown finally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two filters to control the JWT generated.

First Filter is to authenticate and send the JWT to the client when the authentication is successful.

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManger) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManger;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            AuthenticationRequest authRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), 
                    AuthenticationRequest.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException {
        Date expirationDate = DateUtil.getDateAddDays(new Date(), 1);
        String token = Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(new Date()).setIssuer(WebSecurity.ISSUER)
                .setSubject(((ClientDetails)auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, HardCodeUtil.JWT_KEY).compact();
        response.addHeader(WebSecurity.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, WebSecurity.PREFIX_JWT + token);
        response.addHeader(WebSecurity.HEADER_JWT_EXPIRATION_DATE, String.valueOf(expirationDate.getTime()));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ClientExtraParams extraParams = new ClientExtraParams((byte)1);
        String body = mapper.writeValueAsString(new ClientLoginResponse(((ClientDetails)auth.getPrincipal()).getClient(),
                extraParams));
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(body);
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();
    }

}
```

The second Filter is to validate every JWT before access to the resources:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JWTAuthorizationFilter.class.getName());

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(WebSecurity.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(WebSecurity.PREFIX_JWT)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }catch (SignatureException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "JWT SIGNING INVALID");
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "JWT STRUCTURE INVALID");
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "JWT EXPIRED");
            GeneralResponse jwtInvalidResponse = new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.JWT_EXPIRED);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String body = mapper.writeValueAsString(jwtInvalidResponse);
            res.setContentType("application/json");
            res.getWriter().write(body);
            res.getWriter().flush();
            res.getWriter().close();
        }catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "JWT UNSUPPORTED");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "ILLEGAL ARGUMENT JWT ENVIADO");
        }
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(WebSecurity.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);
        if (token != null) {
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(HardCodeUtil.JWT_KEY)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(WebSecurity.PREFIX_JWT, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In your Spring configuration of HttpSecurity add these filters:

```
.and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
```

I implemented this using this library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```